# Next-token prediction with Transformer and uneven sequences

Tags: python, nlp, torch, transformer-model

I am having some trouble implementing a Transformer model that performs next-token prediction. Assuming token embedding was already performed, sequences have different lengths, so a batch is composed of a tensor `src_embeds` of size `(batch_size, max_seq_len, embed_size)` and a boolean tensor `pad_mask` of size `(batch_size, seq_len)` with `True` at positions of padded tokens.

What I want is to pass `src_embeds[:, :-1]` and `pad_mask[:, :-1]` as input to the Transformer, which has to predict `src_embeds[:, 1:]`. I have some specific questions:

1. Do I need an encoder-decoder architecture (i.e. using `TransformerEncoder` and `TransformerDecoder`? Or can I have a `TransformerEncoder` and then a feed-forward that outputs the distribution over the next token?

   - My understanding is that I do not need the decoder part, my encoder will take `src_embeds[:, :-1]`, `pad_mask[:, :-1]` and the attention mask that masks inputs in the future, and will produce an output of size `(batch_size, max_seq_len, out_size)` on which the loss will be computed together with the next tokens, i.e. `src_embeds[:, 1:]`.
2. Given that the model will always start with the first given token at test time, do I need to add BOS tokens?

   - My understanding is no, the BOS token is needed only when we want to produce sentences without having a starting token

My model would be then be the following

```py
class TransformerModel(Module):

    def __init__(self, embed_size: int, out_size: int, max_seq_len: int):
        super().__init__()
        n_head = 8
        dim_feed_forward = 1024
        dropout = 0.0
        n_layers = 2
        self.embed_size = embed_size
        self.pos_encoder = PositionalEncoding(d_model=embed_size, dropout=dropout, max_len=max_seq_len)
        self.pos_encoder_factor = math.sqrt(embed_size)
        self.encoder = TransformerEncoder(
            encoder_layer=TransformerEncoderLayer(
                d_model=embed_size, nhead=n_head, dim_feedforward=dim_feed_forward,
                dropout=dropout, batch_first=True),
            num_layers=n_layers
        )
        self.decoder = Sequential(
            Linear(in_features=embed_size, out_features=embed_size),
            ReLU(),
            Linear(in_features=embed_size, out_features=out_size)
        )

    def forward(self, src_embeds: Tensor, mask: Tensor, pad_mask: Tensor):
        src_embeds = self.pos_encoder(src_embeds * self.pos_encoder_factor)
        src_embeds = self.encoder(src_embeds, mask=mask, src_key_padding_mask=pad_mask)

        decoded = self.decoder(src_embeds)
        return decoded  # Returns the logits for the next token
```

where `mask` is the common upper triangular matrix with zeros on the diagonal generated by

```py
torch.triu(torch.ones(max_seq_len, max_seq_len) * float('-inf'), diagonal=1)
```

3. Am I using correctly the `src_mask` and `key_padding_mask` arguments?
4. I do not want to compute the loss for padded elements. Should I compute the loss with no reduction (`reduction='none')` and multiply it by `~pad_masks.float()` (which would have zeros at padded positions and ones at non-padded positions)? Or is there a nicer way of dealing with padded elements in the loss?